# DD-WRT port forwarding doesn't work for internal subnet

Tags: linux, dd-wrt, iptables

I've a router with dd-wrt firmware. I've setup 2nd IP address via Iptables commands and have portforwarded one port. It works fine. However it doesn't work internally. Trying to go internally for 89.25.1.1:443 won't work. Just externally.

```
# Ip for INTRANET
ifconfig vlan2:1 89.25.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.248 broadcast 89.25.1.15

# Routes for IIS HTTPS
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o vlan2 -s 192.168.51.7 -j SNAT --to 89.25.1.1
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i vlan2 -d 89.25.1.1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.51.7:443
iptables -I FORWARD -i vlan2 -d 192.168.51.7 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

How could I fix this so it works also internally?

Comment: Are you able to ping the external interface?

Comment: Yes. Just forwarding doesn't work.

Comment: What version of DD-WRT are you using?  Have you read this? http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Port_Forwarding_Troubleshooting Specifically the part about NAT loopback being broken since build 15760?

Comment: Although [this topic](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=89353) says that its fixed in 19969.

Comment: I don't have that problem on normal redirect (on main ip) so i guess it works fine. `Firmware: DD-WRT v24SP2-MULTI (05/27/11) std ` SVN revision 17140

Comment: Upgraded it to newest version `DD-WRT v24SP2-MULTI (09/27/12) std - build 20025` still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your interfaces look like. I'm guessing `vlan2` is your external interface, which means the problem is in this rule:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i vlan2 -d 89.25.1.1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.51.7:443
```

The **`-i vlan2`** means the rule only matches if the packet is coming in on the `vlan2` interface - which it isn't, it's coming in from the internal network, so that's `vlan1` or whatever that one's called in your config. To have the same dnat, it should be fine to just leave out the interface restriction with the `-i` parameter completely, i.e. just use

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 89.25.1.1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.51.7:443
```